# RTL Dropdown Problem in Browsers (Windows7 or Vista)

Tags: css, gwt, drop-down-menu, right-to-left

I have problem in RTL drop-down in windows7 or Vista. As you know browsers usually use OS listbox to show these components.

I want to ask how to restyle drop-down with CSS in RTL or if it is not possible, do you know free useful drop-down widget(in GWT)?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Quick and Dirty way is :

```
ListBox list = new ListBox();
    list.addItem("Value one");
    list.addItem("Value two");
    RootPanel.get("comboContainer").add(list);
    list.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("direction", "rtl");
```

Better way would be to do it in your stylesheet though.

Comment: Could you mention the Browser you testing it on? That worked for me using Win7 x64 and Chrome

Comment: If you look at the locale list at http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html?locale=ar you'll see it working in all browsers.
It might be that a third party library could be affecting your UI?

The example I posted has the exact same result. In Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and IE8/7